# Is there a query to check the current WAL size in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I'm using a hosted PostgreSQL database where I don't have shell access.  Is there a query I can use to check the current WAL log size?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you have superuser access, you can use:

```
select * 
from pg_ls_dir('pg_xlog');
```

which will return one row for each file in the directory `pg_xlog`. As the size for a WAL segment is fixed, you can easily calculate the total size by multiplying the number of rows by 16MB:

```
select count(*) * pg_size_bytes(current_setting('wal_segment_size')) as total_size
from pg_ls_dir('pg_xlog') as t(fname)
where fname <> 'archive_status';
```

Alternatively you can use `pg_stat_file()` to return information about the files:

```
select sum((pg_stat_file('pg_wal/'||fname)).size) as total_size
from pg_ls_dir('pg_xlog') as t(fname);
```

---

Starting with Postgres 10 you can use:

```
select sum(size) 
from pg_ls_waldir()
```

Comment: Pg 10 also provides for `pg_current_wal_flush_lsn()`, `pg_current_wal_insert_lsn(),` `pg_current_wal_lsn()` which you can feed to `pg_walfile_name()`

Comment: please note the 16MB size is the default but could be configured to be different

Comment: @Luke404: good point, I have changed the query.

Comment: what's the unit for each query? Bytes?

Comment: @Alex it seems that for the last one it is indeed bytes.