# PostgreSQL Database Data and Log size

Tags: postgresql, monitoring, shrink, database-size

I am looking for a way to list PostgreSQL Database Data and Log sizes.

Using the following command we can check the total database size based on the documentation https://pgpedia.info/p/pg_database_size.html

```
pg_database_size('database_name')
```

I am not really sure if this function displays data and logs summarized together.
Is there any way to get these numbers separately, so we can know how much is the data files and how much is the log files?

Comment: What kind of "logs" are you referring to? The Postgres error log is most certainly not included in that figure as it is used for all databases (and processes) in the instance

Comment: Do you want to monitor equivalent of transacion log? You should monitor WAL files.

Comment: For example, if your instance is full but the databases sizes is only 10% of the instance capacity, it should be the log files -> WAL files. Coming from SQL Server, I thought that each database has each own log file.

Comment: No, Postgres is more like Oracle in this regard. The WAL segments are managed for the whole instance. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal-intro.html

Comment: So any ideas how I can check WAL files size in Azure for Postgres for example?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192564

Comment: If you want you can post a complete answer, so i can accept it, with full information that logs are not per database and we can check them with select sum(size) 
from pg_ls_waldir()

Comment: Be careful, there can be more than one database in a cluster. This query will size all databases: `select datname,pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(datname)) as size from (select datname from pg_database) t;`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, currently I am testing on a single instance for R&D purposes. Although the statement you have displays the database size and not the log, which i believe is already calculated and stored. so the query even on cluster will not perform any data shuffle, right?